# Why do I keep getting nil field values when passing struct pointers in functions?

Tags: go

**Problem:**
I have a struct which contains a map and two slices. When I pass the pointer value, no matter what I do, these collections within the struct are always nil (i.e. cannot append anything to the map or slices).

**Details:**
I cannot figure out why this is happening. I made a seemingly unrelated change (which I can't remember) and now nothing will append to the Map in the struct. I am passing the Map pointer to subsequent functions, but it keeps throwing an error "panic: assignment to entry in nil map".

I pass the pointers for the LinkResource and the LinkReport type values, but it always says the map is nil. I even forcefully Zeroed the LinkReport struct values with make(...) as a debugging test, but when the value is passed to subsequent functions it still claims the Map and Slices are nil; how is this possible and how do I correct it?

**LinkResource**

```
package model

type LinkResource struct {
    ID int
    URL string
    Health string
    Status int
    Message string
}
```

**LinkReport**

```
type LinkReport struct {
    Summary map[string]int
    BrokenLinks []LinkResource
    UnsureLinks []LinkResource
}
```

**Logic That is Throwing the Error**

```
type LinkService struct { }

func (linkService *LinkService) populateLinkReportMetadata(responseCode int, message string, health string, link *model.LinkResource, linkReport *model.LinkReport) {

    linkReport.Summary[health]++
    link.Message = message
    link.Health = health
    link.Status = responseCode

    switch health {
    case constants.Broken:
        linkReport.BrokenLinks = append(linkReport.BrokenLinks, *link)
        break
    case constants.Unsure:
        linkReport.UnsureLinks = append(linkReport.UnsureLinks, *link)
        break
    }
}
```

**Test Function to Reproduce the Problem**

```
func TestPopulateLinkReportMetadata(t *testing.T) {

    link := model.LinkResource{}
    linkReport := model.LinkReport{}

    link.ID = 1234
    link.URL = "http://someurl.com"

    linkService := LinkService{}

    t.Log("After analyzing a LinkResource")
    {
        linkService.populateLinkReportMetadata(http.StatusOK, link.Message, constants.Healthy, &link, &linkReport)

        if linkReport.Summary[constants.Healthy] > 0 {
            t.Logf("The LinkResource should be appended to the %s summary slice %s", constants.Healthy, checkMark)
        } else {
            t.Fatalf("The LinkResource should be appended to the %s summary slice %s", constants.Healthy, ballotX)
        }
    }

}
```

I appreciate any assistance as I am quite perplexed, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example of the error:

```
type linkReport struct {
   summary map[string]int
}

func main() {
   var link linkReport
   // panic: assignment to entry in nil map
   link.summary["month"] = 12
}
```

and a simple fix:

```
var link linkReport
link.summary = make(map[string]int)
link.summary["month"] = 12
```

or you can make a "new" function:

```
func newLinkReport() linkReport {
   return linkReport{
      make(map[string]int),
   }
}

func main() {
   link := newLinkReport()
   link.summary["month"] = 12
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Steven Penny!